# How to add thumbnailphoto to Active Directory user?

Tags: vb.net, powershell, active-directory, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to use VB.Net and PowerShell to update AD photos (thumbnailphotos property). So I used straight PowerShell to do a one-time update of all users' thumbnailphoto property already and that worked. What I would like to do is do a night job that gets picture files that were modified or are new in the past 24 hours. Most parts of my code (getting the last 24 hour edited files and parsing the userlogin by querying an internal database) is working. The part that doesn't work is the PowerShell part that should update the photo.

```vb
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Management.Automation
Imports System.Management.Automation.Runspaces
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Text

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        'Read the number of files that are new in the past 24 hours
        GetFiles()
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Private Sub GetFiles()
        Dim directory = New DirectoryInfo("\\server\share")
        Dim from_date As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)
        Dim to_date As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Dim files = directory.GetFiles().Where(Function(file) file.LastWriteTime >= from_date AndAlso file.LastWriteTime <= to_date)

        'Test to see what file output we are getting
        '===========================================

        For Each file In files
            'Console.WriteLine(file.ToString)
            'Going to function to find user if file is not thumbs.db
            If file.ToString <> "Thumbs.db" Then
                FindUsername(file.ToString())
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub FindUsername(ByVal fileName As String)
        'Calling function to find the user that has the picfile with this name

        Dim userLogin As String = ""

        Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection("Data Source=sqlserver;Initial Catalog=database;Integrated Security=False;User Id=user;Password=password;")
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim returnValue As Object

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT RTRIM(userLogin) AS [userLogin] FROM directory     WHERE picfile='" + fileName + "'"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1

        sqlConnection1.Open()

        returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        'Console.WriteLine(returnValue.ToString + " " + fileName.ToString)
        sqlConnection1.Close()

        If returnValue IsNot Nothing Then
            'Run script with powershell
            updatePhotoInAD(returnValue.ToString, fileName.ToString)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub updatePhotoInAD(userLogin As String, fileName As String)
        'Prepare pipeline for execution

        Dim fileNamewithPath As String = "\\server\share\" + fileName
        Dim commandString As String = String.Format("Set-UserPhoto " + "{0}" + " - PictureData([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes(" + "{1})", userLogin, fileNamewithPath)

        Using PowerShellInstance As PowerShell = PowerShell.Create()
            ' use "AddScript" to add the contents of a script file to the end of the execution pipeline.
            ' use "AddCommand" to add individual commands/cmdlets to the end of the execution pipeline.
            PowerShellInstance.AddScript(commandString)
            ' invoke execution on the pipeline (ignore output)
            PowerShellInstance.Invoke()
        End Using

        Console.WriteLine(userLogin + " " + fileName + " " + commandString)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: The -7 is actually to capture past 7 days instead of 24 hours during testing.

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this remotly? Or is your client where you want to run the script from not part of the domain?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Are you getting an error?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with VB.Net, but shouldn't that be `PowerShellInstance.AddCommand(commandString)`?

Comment: Something else (since otheres already have answered): It's bad design to call `GetFiles()` which calls `FindUsername()` which calls `updatePhotoInAD()`. Finding a username has nothing to do with updating the photo, and finding a user has nothing to do with getting files(pictures). You should move the call to `findusername()` and `updatephotoinad()` into main or another "main"-function.